# Bonding stops working when disconnecting primary interface Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, network-bonding

I have tried to set up bonding between two switches that link to one switch that is linked to a camera (10.0.10.10):

```
Camera
  |
  |
Switch 1 - - - - - - - - 
  |                    |
  | A                  | B
  |                    |
Switch Primary      Switch Secondary
  |                    |
C | enp3s4f0         D | enp3s4f1 
  |                    |
  |                    |
 ---------------------------
 |Ubuntu 18.04             |
 |       bond0             |
 |------------------------ |
```

The goal is to be able to ping the camera if any of connections A/B/C/D die. Currently, if connection A dies, the camera cannot be pinged. If any other connection fails, it can still ping the camera.

This is my 01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s4f0:
      addresses: [ ]
    enp3s4f1:
      addresses: [ ]
    bonds:
      bond0:
        addresses: [ 10.0.10.101/24 ]
        gateway4: 10.0.10.10
        nameservers:
          addresses: [ 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.0 ]
        interfaces: [ enp3s4f0, enp3s4f1 ]
        parameters:
          mode: active-backup
          primary: enp3s4f0
```

After applying the netplan, no errors are thrown:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

The problem is that when A is disconnected, the server still recognizes connection C as active so the bond does not change its interface and therefore it keeps trying to reach the camera from Primary Switch, which isn’t possible.

Comment: There must be a problem between enp3s4f1 and the camera. How is the camera connected to the two switches? Do you have 1 switch, or 3 switches?

Comment: @heynnema There are 3 switches in total. The camera is connected to Switch 1 which is connected to two other switches (enp3s4f1, enp3s4f0), and those are connected to the server. I can ping the camera from enp3s4f0 and enp3s4f1 independently. But the bonding is not working. Whenever the primary interface in the bond is disconnected, the camera can no longer be pinged.

Comment: This is a server, yes? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` with everything connected, and show it again with enp3s4f0 disconnected at the server.

Comment: @heynnema Done. Yes it is a server.

Comment: Are these gigabit switches? You didn't disconnect both ethernet cables, correct?

Comment: Are those gigabit switches (I don't know that based on model #'s). I ask because the links are only 100Mb. And, I don't know if it's important, but the bond shows autonegotiation=off. In the bond parameters, you might try adding `mii-monitor-interval: 10`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @heynnema Yes they are. That command did not work. Same issue!

Comment: If they're gigabit switches, then you've got a cabling problem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Are the actual ports on the switches set to gigabit? Do you have another cable to try... from one of the ethernet ports DIRECTLY to one of the switches? And then rerun the lshw command to check the speed.

Comment: @heynnema I think I found the problem, but no solution. Adding `mii-monitor-interva` works after rebooting the server, but there is another issue: When the enps3f40 switch is disconnected only from Switch 1 but still connected to the server, the server still sees the primary interface (enps3f40) as active even though it was disconnected and therefore it cant ping the camera. If I remove both links from the enps3f40 switch to Switch 1 and to the server, it works, because the server detects enps3f40 as down since it is no longer directly connected to it, and it switches to enps34f1.

Comment: We still need to check the cabling vs size (speed) problem, then the rest might work as expected. But we're making progress. As we get closer, I'll put together a formal answer.

Comment: The camera and gateway4 IP's can't be the same.

Comment: @heynnema It looks like `arp-interval` and `arp-ip-targets` did the trick! I set the camera IP as the `arp-ip-target`. Will confirm this later.

Comment: Great news! Note my prior comment that you've listed the camera IP and the gateway4 IP as 10.0.10.10. Also, I've started a partial answer. Maybe you can help me complete it, then, if it's all still working, you can accept my answer, ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the netplan.io reference page [here](https://netplan.io/reference) we find bond parameters that will help us:

```
arp-interval (scalar)
    Set the interval value for how frequently ARP link monitoring should 
    happen. The default value is 0, which disables ARP monitoring. For the
    networkd backend, this maps to the ARPIntervalSec= property. If no time
    suffix is specified, the value will be interpreted as milliseconds.

arp-ip-targets (sequence of scalars) IPs of other hosts on the link which
    should be sent ARP requests in order to validate that a slave is up. 
    This option is only used when arp-interval is set to a value other than 0.
    At least one IP address must be given for ARP link monitoring to function.
    Only IPv4 addresses are supported. You can specify up to 16 IP addresses.
    The default value is an empty list.
```

So, in the bond0 stanza, we changed:

```
parameters:
  mode: active-backup
  primary: enp3s4f0
```

to:

```
parameters:
  mode: active-backup
  primary: enp3s4f0
  arp-interval: 10
  arp-ip-targets: 10.0.10.10
```

Now when the camera goes offline, the bond0 successfully switches over to the other switch, and gets the camera back online.

Comment: You cannot use mii-monitor-interval and arp-interval at the same time. Error when doing netplan apply. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: @udpcon What about the IP problem with the camera and gateway4?

Comment: I believe I have tried that but it was not relevant. Can confirm when I am near the workspace.

Comment: @udpcon no, the problem is that you've listed the camera IP and the gateway4 IP as 10.0.10.10. They BOTH can't be the same IP. When you find the correct IP's, edit your question, let me know the correct IP's, I'll do a final edit on my answer, then you can accept it if you found it all helpful :-)

Comment: They actually are the same IP :) Would that directly affect the current issue?

Comment: @udpcon How is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure. Thinking a bit further, I think it isn’t right to arp check the camera because we shouldn’t be changing interfaces based on the camera, but based on the switch. What if the camera itself is down? Why should we switch to eth1 if theres no problem with eth0? Ideally Switch 1 would have an IP and we would arp check that instead, which should produce the same result because eth0 wouldnt be able to ping Switch 1 if cable A fails. But now thats depending on hardware (a managed switch) to complete a software task. There should be an easier way.

Comment: @udpcon The way it is right now, we shouldn't care if hardware or software is finding a fault in the system. If the camera can't be found via arp, the hardware should try to reconfigure itself, hoping to bring the cam back online. Of course, a hardware problem with the cam should be obvious, as there won't be any signal, and the hardware won't be able to reconfig to make it work.

Comment: And if there are multiple cameras? (ie. more than the arp-ip-target limit which is 16?). If the 17th camera is working but all of the 16 cameras are dead, the system would keep switching back and forth between the interfaces, wouldn’t it? Because we’ve told it to change interfaces if it cant reach whatever is in the arp-ip-target list. So we couldn’t ping camera 17.

Comment: @udpcon  Now you're changing the base model. Only you know how this all scales up. But for the model we started with, we have an apparent;y working solution :-)

Comment: Yep, for the current model it is a working solution (to be confirmed). Scaling it up requires some more thinking!

Comment: @udpcon for managed switches, they should have an IP that can be used with three entries in arp-ip-targets. It won't tell you that any specific camera is down, only that the switch is down.

Comment: @udpcon To help identify IP's on the network, go to fing.io or fing.com and download the Linux CLI version, or one of the smartphone apps. See https://www.fing.com/products/development-toolkit/?_ga=2.248573253.338913526.1560006515-1593400177.1560006515

Comment: I think its more important to know whether the switch is down because all the cameras would be connected to it, but that would require a managed switch. We would know that a camera is down if we simply cant ping it. Still thinking about how this can scale by adding more switches while remaining as fault tolerant as possible both hardware wise and cable wise... I will accept your answer for now and add to it later.

Comment: @udpcon let me know if I need to update my answer more once you scale it up. You might want to find out if they're managed or unmanaged switches.